# При обращении к полю структуры пишет undefined symbol

Tags: linux, ассемблер, fasm

пробую написать мелкую программку, но не пойму как со структурами работать. в документации нашел только как вот так объявлять структуру. но когда я для windows писал, там по другому структура определялась. но здесь определяется вроде тоже нормально, но я не пойму как получить доступ к её полям. вот код.

```
format ELF64 executable 3

entry start

struc sockaddr_in
{
        port    dw  0
        in_addr dd  0
}

segment readable executable
shellcode:

start:
;------ получаем сокет -------
        mov rdx, 0
        mov rsi, [SOCK_STREAM]
        mov rdi, [PF_INET]
        mov rax, 41
        syscall
        mov [sock], rax
;---- заполнить структуру ----
        mov ax, [server_port]
        xchg al, ah
        mov [s.port], ax
        ret

segment readable writable

path          dq    '/bin/sh'
size          dd    $ - path
sock          dq    0
s             sockaddr_in
server_port   dw    8020

PF_INET       dq    2
SOCK_STREAM   dq    1

sd dd start - shellcode
```

ошибка здесь `mov [s.port], ax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[В примере в документации](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.3.4) показано, что имена полей нужно объявлять с точкой в начале:

> Here is the sample of structure macroinstruction:
>
> ```
> struc point x,y
>  {
>     .x dw x
>     .y dw y
>  }
> ```

Это нужно для того, чтобы метки полей структуры были локальными ("дочерними") по отношению к основной метке (в вашем случае - метка `s`), а не новыми глобальными метками (фактически в вашем коде нет метки `s.port`, но есть глобальная метка `port`). Подробнее о локальных метках - см. предпоследний абзац в разделе [Constants and labels](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#1.2.3).

Соответственно, ваша структура должна выглядеть так:

```
struc sockaddr_in
{
        .port    dw  0
        .in_addr dd  0
}
```

После этого изменения ваш код успешно компилируется.

---

Как это работает:

Структура - это по сути макрос: в месте использования структуры вставляется тело самой структуры. Т.е., когда вы пишете:

```
struc sockaddr_in
{
        port    dw  0
        in_addr dd  0
}

; ...

s             sockaddr_in
```

Это превращается в такой код:

```
s:
port    dw  0
in_addr dd  0
```

Т.е. тут получается просто три глобальных метки. Поля такой структуры будут доступны просто по именам `port` и `in_addr`. Но если вы попытаетесь создать несколько структур, то будет конфликт имен (`error: symbol already defined`), из-за того что будет попытка создать несколько глобальных меток с одинаковым названием.

Если же добавить точки в начало имен полей, то после подстановки будет получаться такой код:

```
s:
.port    dw  0
.in_addr dd  0
```

И поля структуры будут доступны по именам `s.port` и `s.in_addr`.

---

Есть, конечно, другой синтаксис структур, реализованный через макросы (см. [Windows programming headers - Structures](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=win32#1.1)):

```
  struct POINT
    x dd ?
    y dd ?
  ends
```

но для его работы нужно подключать файл `INCLUDE/MACRO/STRUCT.INC` из пакета flat assembler для Windows. В этом варианте синтаксиса точки перед именами ставить не нужно, они проставятся автоматически при разворачивании макросов.